# Finding the value of a variable

Tags: calculus

I'm out of clue to solve this problem, show me the step by step method to grasp the idea how I can retrieve the value of $c$

> If $x^2 + (c - 2)x - c^2 - 3c + 5$ is divided by $x + c$, the remainder is $-1$,  find the value of $c$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{x^2+(c-2)x-c^2-3c+5}{x+c}=x-2+{\frac {-{c}^{2}-c+5}{x+c}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$x^2 + (c - 2)x - c^2 - 3c + 5=(x-c)^2+c(3x-2c-3)-2(x+3)-1$$